# Why does this 'else' throw an error after the 'elif' in Python?

Tags: python

I am having trouble using the else statement and wont function correctly and will not pick it up as a correct syntax how would I correctly get this to work if invalid input was entered..

```
condition = "Start" 
while condition == "Start": 
Dice = int(input("Please select number of dice you would like to use (atleast 1)")) 
Sides = int(input("Please select number of sides on dice you would like to use (atleast 2)")) 
if Dice <= 0 or Sides <= 1:
    condition = "Start"
elif Dice >= 1 and Sides >= 2:
    else:
        condition = "Start"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `pass` keyword in Python to denote an empty block (like you appear to want for your `elif`). Using that, I'd format the code you provided like this:

```
condition = "Start" 
while condition == "Start": 
  Dice = int(input("...")) 
  Sides = int(input("...")) 
  if Dice <= 0 or Sides <= 1:
    condition = "Start"
  elif Dice >= 1 and Sides >= 2:
    pass
  else:
    condition = "Start"
```

Presumably you want to do something else where that `pass` was inserted (since it seems like your positive/correct input block), but it should get you started.